Can you see images? Should I/we report an outage somewhere?
[Edit: I can again see the images today on 5th August '24]
[Edit2: Whoops, false start! Apparently I can now see the images under the link Realistically randomize Rubik's Cube that I reported here and NOTHING else]
[Edit3: I can see all the images today on 6th August '24 - on all sites]
[Edit4: Every now and then, I can't see the images again for a while, so it's an ongoing problem...]
Since Thursday (1st August '24) I can't see any images on entire Stack Exchange. That is, I can't see images that are added to a post using the ✲ CtrlG "Image" button .
So I don't see any images here: Realistically randomize Rubik's Cube
This is what I see instead: image hosted on imgur
I'm mostly active on BSE, but the problem is not limited to that site, e.g. here:
Randomly spawning bitmaps on cnvas
This is how I see the image in the question:



and this is what I see when I click on the link:

and in my answer below I see the "alt" text instead of an image:



and if I open the image in the new tab, I get the "request not right" message...
I was patiently waiting for it to be fixed, a moderator from BSE confirmed he too can't see any message: permalink to chat
And yet some users are still writing questions and answers using SE images, moreover, pasting a link to discord makes Discord embed an image properly, and then I can see it because apparently Discord can access the image, unlike me and Harry, and my problem is limited to the connection with the i.sstatic.net.
So, my question is as in the title, are you aware of the problem? because usually when there's a prolonging technical problem it's displayed in a banner on top of webpages...

Yes, I see it all fine, and I'm sure most others do too, otherwise we'd be flooded with bug reports by now. Something on your side is blocking sstatic.net domain. Might be anything along the chain: from your browser (some adblock) through the ISP, and perhaps DNS issue.

@testing-for-ya good point. And as for no-repro, sadly it only means it can't be reproduced by SE developers, thus can't be solved. :( (except ditching the terrible CloudFlare, but that won't happen.)

Maybe the problem is related to recent switch of the image hosting? Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur has ended - migration complete! - I know that there isn't 1 AUG present on the timeline, but neither is this New service failing on .gif uploads - fixed on 17 JUN...

@testing-for-ya on the other hand - SE's cloudflare's client, not us, and while we can document the issue, we can't exactly lodge a ticket with cloudflare, SE can.

I have the same issue (Can't see the attached images in Stack Exchange questions in Sweden) with some other threads, but I can see the images in your thread.
If this is a problem as suggested by Shadow Wizard, I would not be able to see  any images at all. That is if ISP or DNS Server is blocking the 'sstatic.net' domains, I would not see any images. However, in this case different users are facing issues on different threads. This is difficult to explain, as I checked the same thread in incognito mode and from devices I did not login.

To see the images you need to browse from a different location, or at least use IP of a different location. This can be achieved with some VPN services. Using different device, or the private mode, won't help as you're still in same location and same (or similar) IP address.
