Mostly unable to see images on Stack Exchange sites
A few months ago I largely lost the ability to see images on Stack Exchange sites, but only on my office computer (and all coworkers have the same issue, so it's not my computer, but maybe our office network).
I reported this first in May 2024.
Almost always when I visit a Stack Exchange question that I haven't visited before, all images fail to load. Instead, the alternate text is shown.¹
For example, if I right now open this Q, the second paragraph is not an embedded image, but the hyperlinked alternate text "enter image description here".
If I click the link, I am taken to the PNG file but my browser isn't sent a PNG file, but an HTML page showing a black cat and the following text:

oh no, that request didn't look right
RayID: 8c9202498ab1829a


This is how it looks on my screen:

Actually, now when I pasted this screenshot into this Meta Q, I cannot see the image. Instead, I only see a very good hyperlinked alternate text. If I click the link, I am taken to this PNG file but you serve me an HTML page with a black cat and a new "ray ID": 8c9207d30fba5f02.
A few observations:

My (very limited) experience is that I can see the image the day after my initial attempt to request it.

If I reload the black cat page, it reappears with a new "ray ID".

The person responsible for our office network is baffled and cannot see any reason why this would happen. Our ISP is a very common one in Sweden.


¹ This also makes it clear that the majority of SE users fail to provide ALT texts. Most often I see "Enter image description here". If I were blind, I'd be annoyed by that.

Now I can see the screenshot above.

This is not Cloudflare, Cloudflare blocks will have a status code of 403 or 429. This isn't a block but a 400 error from the back end application. Something in either the browser or at the ISP is preventing the application from receiving the request for the image properly. Making the app team aware of this.

Once the image loads successfully, we tell the browser to cache the image to reduce bandwidth requirements. This means once an image loads correctly once, it'll keep loading correctly until the browser cache is cleared.

Probably related: (Arqade) Is image upload broken right now?

Apparently this is a common issue, maybe especially in Sweden: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401942/145942, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401922/145942
